# NuGet: what should go into TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm working on a customer project; they are hosting the TFS server.

I started work on an existing body of code, in particular one library which is a member of a solution and has been bound to TFS version control. (Little padlock icons appear on this project.)  I added a unit test project to go with it.  I believe that when I added the test project, I did not specify "bind to version control," and so I manually added the project to TFS.  That's all been fine.

I added NuGet package dependencies to both the library and the unit tests. In both cases, the only change in the TFS repo was a new `packages.config` file.  When the customer's build server builds, it grabs the packages from NuGet.  Customer is happy with this; perhaps they shouldn't be?

Then I created another application project, with its own solution, sharing some of the projects in the original solution.  When I created the new project, I did "bind to version control." I added the same package dependencies, but this time the solution got a new `packages` folder containing the package DLLs, and all were added to TFS; there was no `packages.config` file.

I found a link telling me how to "enable package restore" for the solution, and tried it; now I have the `.nuget` directory added to the solution; a `repositories.config` added to `packages`; and changes to the shared `.csproj` files, **and** I still have the package binaries queued up for checkin.

I think I'll need to start over with this new solution, but I want to do the right thing.  It's not clear to me if managing packages using only a `packages.config` is the right thing to do. I found a [post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/01/29/nuget-package-restore-considered-harmful/) discouraging the use of package restore.

I'm working with the Express edition of VS2013, if that makes a difference.

Comment: See: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

Not checkin in the binaries is what you want. Not using the "Enable Package Restore" is better. The other project probably has a `.tfignore` file which prevents the binaries from being added. See: http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build

Answer (score 1):

You should checkin the .nuget directory having the nuget.config file ,package.config file in the project, packages folder with repositories.config and the project file changes.

You should not checkin the binaries in package folder they will be downloaded during the build from nuget.